# How to make checkboxes with images

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have default checkboxes on my website, with only text on every checkbox(e.g. [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox)).

Does it possible to design the checkboxes to have images on them? and maybe to put "v" mark on a checkbox if it been chosen?

---

I want it to look something like:
[image]

Comment: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: I tried to find a way to design checkboxes with images, but i didnt find any resource to help me. I ask if any of you guys know any way to do it? even if you can lead me to any opensource, or give simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can simulate an image based checkbox using a label

```css
input {
  display: none
}

/*  switch image  */
label[for="chk1"] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100/f00);
}
#chk1:checked ~ label[for="chk1"] {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100/ff0);
}

/*  add content  */
label[for="chk2"] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
#chk2:checked ~ label[for="chk2"]::after {
  content: 'V';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox">

<label for="chk1"></label>
<label for="chk2"></label>

<div>Click a box to toggle it</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look really well. :P

Comment: @K.Daniek This is not an attempt to make it look good, it shows how to get an image based checkbox

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I think that jquery would deal with this quicker and better than pure css.

Comment: @K.Daniek Why to use script for stuff meant for CSS?? ... I really don't understand this _jQuery madness_, to use it for everything

Comment: I'm a jQuery psycho fan, maybe that's why. :P

Comment: @K.Daniek I figured ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think most people put images in their checkboxes. They either make an image act like a checkbox like @LGSon did, or they wrap an image and checkbox together inside of a div. Something like this:

```js
function toggleCheck(sibling) {
  var checkBox = sibling.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
}
```

```css
.image-box {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E9E8E7;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.image-box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" onClick="toggleCheck(this);" />
  <input id="dogs" type="checkbox" name="dogs" value="Dog">
  <label for="dogs">I like dogs</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why on earth do you use a `span` and script what can be done with a `label` and no script??

Comment: LGSon, thanks for the feedback, though as a side-note, your pretentious tone is a bit off-putting on a Q&A site designed for novices to find help.

I used a span and script because I was already using the script to allow clicking on the image so it made sense to me to reuse it. But label is probably a better choice there so I've updated my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Didn't intend to put anyone off, so sorry if I did, simply wanted to point out to not use script but a label, which is made especially for these things, ... and btw, SO is not a QA site for novices